# Docker cli hangs randomly for a few minutes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Around one month ago we have started experiencing strange behavior while using docker cli.

Sometimes when invoking docker commands such as: docker-compose pull, docker-compose logs it hangs for few minutes. If we break it, the same issue appears again. However, if we are patient enough to wait for the results, the issue disappears for some time.

Furthermore, the same issue appears when we are inside a container and try to invoke simple commands like ls but the web application that runs inside containers is working fine.

We tried reinstalling whole system from scratch but it didn’t help. There are no strange activities going on the machine. There are no peaks in CPU, disk or RAM usage. We are not experiencing this issue on our old machines (the only difference so far is version of docker: 19.03.1 – we are now checking if downgrading will help but it is not that easy as the issue appears randomly).

- Machine: Google Cloud Compute: n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB memory,
  40GB SSD)
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- docker: 19.03.2
- docker-compose: 1.24.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is finally gone after installing docker engine 19.03.5.